# How to pass CloudKit data directly into a Text() instead of into a list

Tags: swiftui, cloudkit

I am trying to pass a string from an array into a Text(), but can only make it work by passing it through a list first? I have tried every combination of class.struct.item or struct.item etc please let me know how I can pass it directly into a Text() for use in other views.

```
import SwiftUI

struct WorkoutView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var workoutElements: WorkoutElements
    @State private var newWorkout = WorkoutElement(redWorkout: "")

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(workoutElements.workouts) { item in
                VStack {
                    Text(item.redWorkout)
                }
            }

    }
    .onAppear {
        // MARK: fetch from CloudKit
        WorkoutFetcher.fetch { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let newWorkout):
                self.workoutElements.workouts.append(newWorkout)
                print("succesfully fetched Item")
            case .failure(let err):
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
 }
}
struct WorkoutView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        WorkoutView()
    }
}

// this works for a list
//List(workoutElements.workouts) { item in
    //VStack {
        //Text(item.redWorkout)
    //}
//}
// but this doesn't work for Text()
// Text(workoutElements.workouts.redworkouts)
// Text(workouts.redworkouts)
//etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just to join them together, it can be as follows (as far as I see your model)

```
Text("\(workoutElements.workouts.reduce("") { $0 + $1.redWorkout })")
```

if any separator is needed, then just replace with something like

```
$0 + $1.redWorkout + ". "
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! 100% don't understand why but will reason it out.